# Right bracket marker in tikzpicture axis to draw closed set

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, tikz-pic

I'm trying to draw a simple set interval with left/right paranthis for open sets and left/right brackets for closed sets. Here's how I'm drawing it:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis y line=none, axis lines=left, axis line style={-},
  xmin=-1, xmax=11, ymin=0, ymax=1, xlabel=$\mathbb{R}$, restrict y to domain=0:1, xtick={0,...,10}, extra x ticks = {0}, point meta=explicit symbolic, axis lines = middle,
  scatter/classes={open={mark=*,draw=magenta,fill=white},closed={mark=*,red}, closedleft={mark=text,text mark=[,color=black},closedright={mark=text,text mark=],color=black},openleft={mark=text,text mark=(,color=black},openright={mark=text,text mark=),color=black}, point={mark=*,red}},
  %axis line style={latex-latex}
]
\addplot[scatter,blue,ultra thick] table [y expr=0,meta index=1, header=false] {
    0 closedleft
    4 closedright
};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$A$}] at (axis cs:-0.5,0.02) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
```

Here's how that looks:

[image: Attempt at closed set]

You can see the issue, the right bracket is missing, but the left bracket shows up just fine. A hint as to what's going on can be seen when I change the `closedright` marker to a word with a right bracket inside it:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis y line=none, axis lines=left, axis line style={-},
  xmin=-1, xmax=11, ymin=0, ymax=1, xlabel=$\mathbb{R}$, restrict y to domain=0:1, xtick={0,...,10}, extra x ticks = {0}, point meta=explicit symbolic, axis lines = middle,
  scatter/classes={open={mark=*,draw=magenta,fill=white},closed={mark=*,red}, closedleft={mark=text,text mark=[,color=black},closedright={mark=text,text mark=wo]rd,color=black},openleft={mark=text,text mark=(,color=black},openright={mark=text,text mark=),color=black}, point={mark=*,red}},
  %axis line style={latex-latex}
]
\addplot[scatter,blue,ultra thick] table [y expr=0,meta index=1, header=false] {
    0 closedleft
    4 closedright
};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$A$}] at (axis cs:-0.5,0.02) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
```

[image: Hint of cause of issue]

It seems like right brackets specifically act as sort of terminators for text markers.
Anyone know what could be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to confuse the parser, it suffices to wrap the brackets in `{` and `}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis y line=none, axis lines=left, axis line style={-},
      xmin=-1, xmax=11, ymin=0, ymax=1, xlabel=$\mathbb{R}$, restrict y to domain=0:1, xtick={0,...,10}, extra x ticks = {0}, point meta=explicit symbolic, axis lines = middle,
      scatter/classes={open={mark=*,draw=magenta,fill=white},closed={mark=*,red}, closedleft={mark=text,text mark={[},color=black},closedright={mark=text,text mark={]},color=black},openleft={mark=text,text mark={(},color=black},openright={mark=text,text mark={)},color=black}, point={mark=*,red}},
      %axis line style={latex-latex}
    ]
    \addplot[scatter,blue,ultra thick] table [y expr=0,meta index=1, header=false] {
        0 closedleft
        4 closedright
    };
    \node[coordinate,label=above:{$A$}] at (axis cs:-0.5,0.02) {};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you!